# Executing BatchFile from C# program

Tags: c#

I am writing the batch file and executing it through C# program.

**Writing Batch file :**

I will get the Path, Executable name and arguments from app.config and write them to a batch file.

**Executing Batch file :**

Once I write the batch file I pass the file name to below function which executes the batch file to launches an application.

**Problem :**

My program will write a lot of batch files which are executed immediately after each and every file is written. I find that, some times the applications are not started which means that batch files are not executed. I didn't even get any error messages or prompts for this failure of batch file execution.

**Expected solution :**

Any problem in executing the batch file, I should be able to log it or prompt an error.

**Code that executes Batch File :**

```
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            procinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            procinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procinfo);

            System.IO.StreamReader stream = System.IO.File.OpenText(BatchPath + LatestFileName);
            System.IO.StreamReader sroutput = process.StandardOutput;
            System.IO.StreamWriter srinput = process.StandardInput;

            while (stream.Peek() != -1)
            {
                srinput.WriteLine(stream.ReadLine()); 
            }

            Log.Flow_writeToLogFile("Executed .Bat file : " + LatestFileName);
            stream.Close();
            process.Close();
            srinput.Close();
            sroutput.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your problem lies specifically but I've had no problems with the following code:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("xyz.cmd", FileMode.Create)) {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file)) {
        sw.Write("@echo ====================\n");
        sw.Close();
    }
}

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "xyz.cmd";
//p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
//String s = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
//while (s != null) {
//    MessageBox.Show(s);
//    s = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
//}
p.WaitForExit();
```

Obviously that's been cut down a bit for the purposes of hiding my "secret sauce" but that's code currently being used in production without issues.

I do have one question. Why don't you execute the `cmd` file directly rather than running `cmd.exe`?

Probably the first thing I'd do is to print out the `BatchPath + LatestFileName` value to see if you're creating any weirdly named files which would prevent `cmd.exe` from running them.

Comment: I create a .Bat file and execute in cmd.exe. In this case where is the XYZ.cmd ? Am i missing something here ? Once i write a batchfile i name it as "string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy[HH-mm-ss-fffff]}", dt);" to make each batch file name unique. Help...Thanks.

Comment: @Anuya, you're running `cmd.exe` and passing each line of the batch file to its standard input. That seems a convoluted way to do it. Since the batch file is already on disk, I'd just run that instead of `cmd.exe`, then you don't have to worry about sending the individual lines to it. Just replace `xyz.cmd` in my given code with your own batch file name (based on the date/time). My `using` bit is just there to show you how I created the batch file. The actual running starts with the  `Process p =...` bit.